# How can I define generic paths?

Tags: panels, 10

I need to be able to handle multiple paths using Page Manager and its Layout Builder variant.

I didn't find any up-to-date answer to this question in other posts.

That works well when I create separate paths like /base, /base/{level1}, or /base/{level1}/{level2}.

The problem is that on each above page settings are exactly the same and I would like to handle it with just one page and its configuration. I simply would like to avoid having to modify each variant each time any change will be made to in layout builder.

Something like /base/% that will capture all routes starting from base, no matter what is the depth level of the URL. Using just /base doesn't work, unfortunately.

What would be the best option to achieve that result (without resigning from Page Manager which is not an option at the moment)?